# python json.decoder.JSONDecodeError while writing to a json

Tags: python, json

I try to write to a empty json file in python like this.

```
def add_to_json(name, price):
    data = {str(name): str(price)}
    with open("produse.json", 'r+', encoding="utf-8") as file:
        json_file = json.load(file)
        json_file.update(data)
        file.seek(0)
        json.dump(json_file, file)
```

I got some weird error message when I run the code : `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`. I think maybe is from `json.load()`?

Comment: If you give the full exception, then it will explain which line was causing the error. It's likely your `produse.json` is not really a json file. What are the first 3 lines of your `produse.json` file?

Comment: In fact I think that file is empty.

Comment: @RobertSeaman the file is empty

Comment: if file is empty then there is nothing to read and nothing to convert so `json.load()`  gives you this error. Maybe you should first read it as normal string and use `json.loads(string)` only if string is not empty. Or use try/except to catch it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to check if the file is empty:

```
import json


def add_to_json(name, price):
    newObject = {str(name): str(price)}
    with open("produse.json", 'r+', encoding="utf-8") as file:
        data = file.read().strip()  # Just to be safe: Remove all whitespaces.
        json_file = json.loads(
            data or '{}'
        )  # data evaluates to None if empty. If None use a empty JSON string!
        json_file.update(newObject)
        file.seek(0)
        json.dump(json_file, file)


add_to_json('foo', '2.0')
# Verify:
print(open("produse.json", 'r').read())
```

Out:

```
{"foo": "1.0"}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem.